# Android OpenGl 2.0 ES force device reboot

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, nexus-4

I currently try switching to OpenGL ES 2.0. I load two textures with 2048x2048 pixel and render some parts off the textures. The app works on HTC One S, HTC Desire S, HTC Sensation, Asus Iconia A100 and Nexus 7. On Nexus 4 and the new HTC One the app shows a black screen for 1 min following by a device restart. LogCat doesn't show exceptions or errors.

The draw function of my SurfaceView will never be called.
Any suggestion?

```
[2013-04-29 05:41:04 - PinguActivity] Android Launch!
[2013-04-29 05:41:04 - PinguActivity] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-29 05:41:04 - PinguActivity] Performing com.asgardsoft.pingu.PinguActivity activity launch
[2013-04-29 05:41:04 - PinguActivity] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-04-29 05:41:10 - PinguActivity] Uploading PinguActivity.apk onto device '************'
[2013-04-29 05:41:11 - PinguActivity] Installing PinguActivity.apk...
[2013-04-29 05:41:16 - PinguActivity] Success!
[2013-04-29 05:41:16 - PinguActivity] Starting activity com.asgardsoft.pingu.PinguActivity on device ************
[2013-04-29 05:41:17 - PinguActivity] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.asgardsoft.pingu/.PinguActivity }
[2013-04-29 05:41:17 - PinguActivity] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.asgardsoft.pingu' on port 8600
```

LogCat:

```
 04-29 05:41:15.339: E/Trace(11875): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-29 05:41:15.349: I/System.out(11875): Sending WAIT chunk
04-29 05:41:15.349: W/ActivityThread(11875): Application com.asgardsoft.pingu is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-29 05:41:15.549: I/System.out(11875): Debugger has connected
04-29 05:41:15.549: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:15.749: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:15.949: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:16.150: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:16.350: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:16.550: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:16.760: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:16.960: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:17.161: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:17.361: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:17.561: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:17.761: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:17.961: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:18.162: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:18.362: I/System.out(11875): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-29 05:41:18.562: I/System.out(11875): debugger has settled (1460)
04-29 05:41:19.253: D/libc(11875): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40cc4645, tls=0x53a99f00, arg=0x5319adc8
04-29 05:41:19.263: D/libc(11875): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40cc4645
04-29 05:41:19.263: D/libc(11875): , tls=0x53a99f00, arg=0x5319adc8
04-29 05:41:27.402: D/libc(11875): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x40cc4645, tls=0x53b99f00, arg=0x4f5584f8
04-29 05:41:27.402: D/libc(11875): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x40cc4645
04-29 05:41:27.402: D/libc(11875): , tls=0x53b99f00, arg=0x4f5584f8
04-29 05:41:27.442: I/Choreographer(11875): Skipped 480 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 05:41:27.522: I/Adreno200-EGL(11875): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB4.04.01.02.16.028_msm8960_JB_REL_RB4.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
04-29 05:41:27.522: I/Adreno200-EGL(11875): Build Date: 12/06/12 Thu
04-29 05:41:27.522: I/Adreno200-EGL(11875): Local Branch: 
04-29 05:41:27.522: I/Adreno200-EGL(11875): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb4.2
04-29 05:41:27.522: I/Adreno200-EGL(11875): Local Patches: NONE
04-29 05:41:27.522: I/Adreno200-EGL(11875): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
04-29 05:41:27.562: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x53b9a000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:60
04-29 05:41:27.562: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40128000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:62
04-29 05:41:27.602: D/libc(11875): pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x51271e31, tls=0x54010f00, arg=0x501361d0
04-29 05:41:27.602: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54011000 size:1044480 offset:0 fd:65
04-29 05:41:27.602: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40757000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:67
04-29 05:41:27.622: D/libc(11875): pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x51271e31
04-29 05:41:27.622: D/libc(11875): , tls=0x54010f00, arg=0x501361d0
04-29 05:41:29.504: W/Adreno200-ES20(11875): <process_gl_state_enables:463>: GL_INVALID_ENUM
04-29 05:41:29.644: I/dalvikvm-heap(11875): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.853MB for 16777232-byte allocation
04-29 05:41:34.259: I/dalvikvm-heap(11875): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.849MB for 16777232-byte allocation
04-29 05:41:39.945: I/dalvikvm-heap(11875): Grow heap (frag case) to 26.851MB for 16777232-byte allocation
04-29 05:41:40.345: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54333000 size:1044480 offset:0 fd:69
04-29 05:41:40.345: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x407d8000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:71
04-29 05:41:40.536: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x54432000 size:1044480 offset:0 fd:73
04-29 05:41:40.536: D/memalloc(11875): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40901000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:75
```

thanks
ronald

Comment: If your draw function isn't even being called it could mean that you are doing something wrong in your opengl initialization code. You are probably doing something that is not supported by the Adreno graphics card in the Nexus 4. If you post some code it might be helpful. Also make sure your texture sizes and any other assumptions you are making are within the GPU limits by querying the driver for the same.